# How to stop Word 2007 from overlapping images?

Tags: microsoft-word

I opened a Word 2003 document in Word 2007 and if I delete or add a line, then the images from the document won't move. They simply overlap the text and I have to move each image whenever I edit the text. Any fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to re-set your text wrapping around the picture in question.  Click on the picture, and I think there's an option in the ribbon menu called picture, and within that menu option there should be an option called text wrapping.  Also take a look at the text position, you can set it to front or back and stuff like that.

Hope that helps.